# Is using OpenSSH Authentication Agent on Windows 11 a secure practice?

Tags: windows, ssh, openssh

I use a passphrase on my SSH key used for git. I wanted to be able to use the same git for a few scripts I run to clone/pull a bunch of my repos.

I discovered that I don't have to repeatedly enter my passphrase if I configure my system to use the OpenSSH Authentication Agent.

I am curious if this is secure. I noticed that it did not ask me for my passphrase after reboot, which indicated that OpenSSH Authentication Agent is persisting my passphrase to disk somewhere.

Is this a secure practice?